# Is $N_G(S)=N_G(\langle S\rangle)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Related question: [What would be a counterexample of $N_G(T)\not\subset N_G(S)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/998280/44669)

Let $G$ be a group.

Let $S$ be a **subset** of $G$.

Then, is $N_G(S)=N_G(\langle S\rangle)$?

I have proved that $N_G(S)\subset N_G(\langle S\rangle)$, but I'm not sure about the other direction. Is there a counterexample for this?

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Hint: They are equal.

Comment: Note: Typographically, ${<S>}\  \ne \langle S\rangle$. (I edited the question accordingly.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @QuangHoang are you sure?

Comment: To me, $N_G(S)$ is the least normal subgroup containing $S$. So yes, I'm sure: Since $N_G(S)$ contains $\langle S\rangle$, it contains $N_G(\langle S\rangle)$ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $D_3=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=1,ab=b^2a\rangle$, and $S=\{1,b\}$. Then $a\in N(\langle S\rangle)\setminus N(S)$.